# What tools do you like to use for LiDAR Point Cloud Analysis and Manipulation?

Tags: ros, ros2, lidar, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Are there open source tools you like to use for manipulating and analyzing LiDAR data (.pcd, .las, .laz)? Generally the problems I am trying to solve are related to robotics.

Here's a list of features I am looking for preferably also having a GUI as an interface.

- Labeling pointcloud data and their classes
- [Scale.ai](https://scale.com/robotics) (Commercial)
- [Segments.ai](https://segments.ai/point-cloud-labeling) (Commercial)
- [Labelbox](https://learn.labelbox.com/labelbox-vs-scale-ai/?utm_medium=paid-search&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Core-Competitor&utm_term=scale%20ai%20labeling&utm_device=c&_bt=649130842505&_bm=p&_bn=g&gclid=CjwKCAiAr4GgBhBFEiwAgwORre309A0HO5JX8ZmnnBbID7jRaMBW8_weNSbFf9H067moAdUosR15KRoCgc4QAvD_BwE) (Commercial)
- [Label Cloud](https://github.com/ch-sa/labelCloud)
- Manually adjusting LiDAR frames/entire sections (translations, rotations) with visualization/tools. Not just applying transformations via script.
- Viewing the pointcloud data and in different modes (intensity, RGB, distance, etc.)
- RVIZ
- pcl_viewer
- [Cloud compare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/)
- Projecting LiDAR points onto an image or plane for creating 2D Vector maps
- [Tier IV](https://tools.tier4.jp/feature/vector_map_builder/)
- Tools to assist in auto-stitching lidar frames together to create a map
- Converting between point cloud formats
- [PDAL](https://pdal.io/en/latest/)
- Comparing point cloud data files
- [LAStools](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/)
- [Cloud compare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/)
- General filtering, outlier removal, and manipulation
- [LAStools](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/)
- pcl library

I'm sure I am missing other useful features and undervaluing some tools I listed above (pcl_library, LAStools, CloudCompare). I am a LiDAR newbie looking to deep dive into all that is wonderful with LiDARs and robotics!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413043/what-tools-do-you-like-to-use-for-lidar-point-cloud-analysis-and-manipulation?/) by [xparr45](https://answers.ros.org/users/71426/xparr45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After trying out various tools, I really like using PDAL for quick conversions and downsizing of your pointcloud.

Cloudcompare has been very helpful for almost everything else and can do most of what PDAL does. **HIGHLY recommend.**

---

Originally posted by [xparr45](https://answers.ros.org/users/71426/xparr45/) with karma: 13 on 2023-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1